# Need help in downloading ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to download in Virtual Box and getting wrong kernal.
It states I should use I86-cpu. Am I downloading the wrong program?

Answer (score 2):

It does not say I86. But I would assume i386? That means you need the 32-bit Ubuntu version.

- [32-bit 16.04.1 torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.180146087.260058970.1458070813)
- [32-bit 14.04.4 torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.219472794.260058970.1458070813)
- [32-bit 16.04.1 direct download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso?_ga=1.180677412.260058970.1458070813)
- [32-bit 14.04.4 direct download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso)

Both desktop version. [More versions here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

Comment: I'm curious, what's your rationale behind linking to the torrent files, instead of the ISO?

Comment: oh? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=16.04.1&architecture=i386

Comment: I just changed the `architecture` parameter from `amd64` to `i386` :P

Comment: now if that would have been a pokemon I might have caught it :D didn't even think about that :D